# Google Maps border on Canvas

Tags: google-maps, css, border

I've check new google maps look and it has a kind of border with shadow on the canvas. How is posible to make that? looks pretty well.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score -1, accepted):

It's just a box shadow that's set to be an interior (most box shadows are exterior, aka drop shadows). The CSS is pretty simple:

```
#inner-shadow {
-moz-box-shadow: inset 0 0 5px #888;
-webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 0 5px#888;
box-shadow: inner 0 0 5px #888;
}
```

And the html:

```
<div id="inner-shadow">
<!-- Google Map here -->
</div>
```

Comment: I forgot to mention, that trick only works in modern browsers. For anything older than IE9, you'll need to either use the filter:xyz in the css or not worry about the shadow with those users.

Comment: The shadow appears under gmap's box for me, so not visible